# Module in Google Colab not updating after change

Tags: module, google-colaboratory

I changed the method in a module, say *util.py* saved in google drive from

```
def return_no(num1,num2):
   return num1*num2
```

to

```
def return_no(num1,num2):
   return num1+num2
```

But calling the method from google colab is returning the multiplication of the two number, even though I have changed it to summation.
Any suggestion on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

It takes some time to reflect on changes made to your module.
Restart your runtime and try, it should reflect.

runtime -> restart runtimes or Ctrl+M